# Linux Block Filter Driver

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, block

I have a basic linux block filter driver (taken from https://github.com/asimkadav/block-filter ) which i want to extend to do the following:

1. Record IO pattern on device
2. Duplicate IO to another device

I am trying to add to debugging info to "misc_request_fn" function but the kernel keep crashing.

I am not sure what i am doing wrong. 
further more - how can i identify write operation and duplicate it to another device ?

> ```
> #include <linux/pci.h>
> #include <linux/bug.h>
> #include <linux/kallsyms.h>
> #include <linux/kernel.h>
> #include <linux/module.h>
> #include <linux/rtnetlink.h>
> #include <linux/lockdep.h>
> #include <linux/slab.h>
> #include <linux/highmem.h>
> #include <linux/swap.h>
> #include <linux/completion.h>
> #include <linux/kthread.h>
> #include <linux/delay.h>
> #include <linux/blkdev.h>
>
> #ifndef _MISCDEVICE_H
> #define _MISCDEVICE_H
>
> // Driver number
> #define MISC_MINOR      45
>
>
> // Fault injection op-codes
> //
> #define MISC_GET 0x101
> #define MISC_PUT 0x102
>
> #endif
>
>
>
> static struct miscdevice misc_help;
> static struct block_device *blkdev;
> static void (*original_request_fn) (struct request_queue*, struct bio*);
>
>
> /* Sample ioctl code - not used. Can be used to trigger on/off filtering. */
> static long mischelp_ioctl(/*struct inode *inode,*/ struct file *fp,
>                 unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg) {
>
>         if (cmd == MISC_GET)    {
>                 printk ("Can perform get ops %d.\n", (int) arg);
>         }
>
>         if (cmd == MISC_PUT)    {
>                 printk ("Can perform put ops %d.\n", (int) arg);
>         }
>
>         return 0;
> }
>
>
> struct file_operations misc_fops = {
>         .unlocked_ioctl = mischelp_ioctl,
>         .owner = THIS_MODULE,
>         .mmap = NULL,
> };
>
> void misc_request_fn(struct request_queue *q, struct bio *bio) {
>         //printk ("we are passing bios.\n");
>         // here is where we trace requests...
>         printk ("IO size %d\n",bio->bi_size);
>         original_request_fn (q, bio);
>         return;
> }
>
>
> void register_block_device(char *path)  {
>
>         struct request_queue *blkdev_queue = NULL;
>
>         if (path == NULL)       {
>                 printk ("Block device empty.\n");
>                 return;
>         }
>
>         printk ("Will open %s.\n", path);
>
>         blkdev = lookup_bdev(path);
>
>         if (IS_ERR(blkdev))     {
>                 printk ("No such block device.\n");
>                 return;
>         }
>
>         printk ("Found block device %p with bs %d.\n", blkdev, blkdev->bd_block_size);
>         blkdev_queue = bdev_get_queue(blkdev);
>         original_request_fn = blkdev_queue->request_fn;
>         blkdev_queue->request_fn = misc_request_fn;
> }
>
> void unregister_block_device(void)      {
>         struct request_queue *blkdev_queue = NULL;
>
>         blkdev_queue = bdev_get_queue(blkdev);
>
>         if ((blkdev_queue->request_fn != NULL) &&
>                         (original_request_fn != NULL))  {
>
>                 blkdev_queue->request_fn = original_request_fn;
>                 printk ("Successfully unregistered block device.\n");
>         }
> }
>
>
>
> int init_module(void)   {
>         int retval = 0;
>         static char *mischelp_name = "mischelp";
>
>         misc_help.minor = MISC_MINOR;
>         misc_help.name = mischelp_name;
>         misc_help.fops = &misc_fops;
>         retval = misc_register(&misc_help);
>
>         if (retval)
>                 return retval;
>
>         register_block_device("/dev/sdg");
>
>         printk ("block tracer initialized successfully.\n");
>         return 0;
> }
>
> void cleanup_module(void){
>         int number = 0;
>
>         unregister_block_device();
>
>         number = misc_deregister(&misc_help);
>         if (number < 0) {
>                 printk ("misc_deregister failed. %d\n", number);
>         }
>
>         printk ("It's over for block tracer.. \n");
> }
> ```

Comment: Where does it crash?  Try checking if `bio` is NULL before dereferencing it.

Comment: it will hang once i write IO to the monitored device.I am assuming it is hanging when trying to printk "bio->bi_size" (commenting out the printk line - issue doesn't occur) . system completely hangs so it is hard to see where exactly it crashed

Comment: What happens if you comment-out the `original_request_fn()`?  Perhaps this is a re-entrancy issue.  I would think that if the hang/crash were in `printk()` from dereferencing a null pointer it would give you a stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the below line from your code

*blkdev = lookup_bdev(path);*

and use,

*blkdev = blkdev_get_by_path(path, FMODE_READ | FMODE_WRITE, NULL);*

This should fix the kernel reboot problem.

Comment: Kernel Panic is still happening after applying the change

Comment: @curious, Pls refer the below code which helped us to get our task going,   https://gist.github.com/prashants/3839380